# When __repr__() is called?

Tags: python

`print OBJECT` calls `OBJECT.__str__()`, then when `OBJECT.__repr__()` is called? I see that `print OBJECT` calls `OBJECT.__repr__()` when `OBJECT.__str__()` doesn't exist, but I expect that's not the only way to call `__repr__()`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
repr(obj)
```

calls

```
obj.__repr__
```

the purpose of `__repr__` is that it provides a 'formal' representation of the object that is supposed to be a expression that can be `eval`ed to create the object. that is,

```
obj == eval(repr(obj))
```

*should*, but does not always in practice, yield `True`

I was asked in the comments for an example of when `obj != eval(repr(obj))`.

```
class BrokenRepr(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "not likely"
```

here's another one:

```
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> repr(con)
'<sqlite3.Connection object at 0xb773b520>'
>>>
```

Comment: Why does obj == eval(repr(obj)) not always give True? Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: For a complex object, such as a file, it will not necessarily return True.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: obj == eval(type('myclass', (), {}))

Answer (score 11):

Not only does `__repr__()` get called when you use `repr()`, but also in the following cases:

1. You type `obj` in the shell and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. You ever print an object in a dictionary/tuple/list. E.g.: `print [u'test']` does not print `['test']`

Answer (score 3):

`repr(obj)` calls `obj.__repr__`.

This is intended to clearly describe an object, specially for debugging purposes. [More info in the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=repr#object.__repr__)

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.x, `` `obj` `` will end up calling `obj.__repr__()`.  It's shorthand for `repr()`.