# Problems understanding __repr__, doesn't print anything even I've decleared it

Tags: python, class, object, repr

So yesterday I tried to use **repr** and **str** in my code for printing objects from list. Here just small example code where I run to same problem.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I want this out"

    def __str__(self):
        return "this comes out"

def main():

    k = Something()
    k
    print(k)

main()
```

What is printed:

> this comes out
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Why can't i get the **repr** out of my object even though I have given it line to return when object is called?

Comment: You could [`inspect` who the caller was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method) and adapt accordingly

Comment: You could always write __str__ to return __repr__..
`def __str__(self): return self.__repr__()`

Comment: @Magnus I think OP wants different output based on what method is called

Comment: You didn't get it because you never called it... `repr(k)` will give you what you want.

Comment: @Adelin I agree. I just wanted to suggest it, but perhaps it was obvious.

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764360/when-repr-is-called

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.pythoncentral.io/what-is-the-difference-between-__str__-and-__repr__-in-python/

Comment: @Adelin That's not true, if an object contains only `__repr__`, `print` will use `__repr__`. But if an object contains `__str__`, `print` will choose `__str__` first.

Comment: The line with `k` by itself doesn't call `repr`; only expression statements executed *directly* from the REPL do so.

Comment: Even with repr(k) I only get out the string in __str__(). Really don't get this thing.

Answer (score 0):

`__repr__()` and `__str__()` are used for different purposes.

- `__repr__'s` goal is to be unambiguous
- `__str__'s` goal is to be
  readable

There is a great write-up [on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python#2626364).

In your case, your code simply references `k` in hopes that this will display the repr version of `k`. This works on an interactive prompt, but does NOT work within a script. Within a script, to see the `repr` representation of your object, you must use the `repr()` function. To see the `str()` representation of your object, you normally must use the `str()` function.

Notably, the `print()` function defaults to displaying the `str` representation, which is why you can print it without explicitly calling `str()` first.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I want this out"

    def __str__(self):
        return "this comes out"

def main():

    k = Something()
    print("repr:", repr(k))
    print("str:", str(k))
    print("defaults to calling str() if available: ", k)

main()

repr: I want this out
str: this comes out
defaults to calling str() if available:  this comes out
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways your code was run by the interpreter.
First is REPL context(iPython shell, or ipdb debug env), in this situation, python interpreter will call `__repr__` function, I tried below in a ipython env, it work like this:

```
In [1]: class Something(object):
   ...:
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return 'in __repr__'
   ...:

In [2]: k = Something()

In [3]: k
Out[3]: in __repr__
```

Second, when you start your script or project by `python xxx.py`, the interpreter will call the `__str__`.

I think you just tried the second way.

Hope this can help you a bit.