# python 3, how print function changes output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

The following were what I did in python shell. Can anyone explain the difference?

> > > datetime.datetime.now()
> > >       datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 29, 21, 34, 10, 847635)
> > >
> > > print(datetime.datetime.now())
> > >       2018-09-29 21:34:26.900063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the result of calling `repr` on the datetime value, the second is the result of calling `str` on a datetime.
The Python shell calls `repr` on values other than None before printing them, while `print` tries `str` before calling `repr` (if `str` fails).

This is not dependent on the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

When print is called, the inner `__str__()` of class `datetime` is called. This function calls `isoformat()` and returns the date in ISO format.

```
    def __str__(self):
        "Convert to string, for str()."
        return self.isoformat(sep=' ')
```

When an object's name is entered to the shell, [`__repr__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764790/10365325) is called and returns a formal representation of the object.